# Parameterized MySQLdb SELECT, 1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: python, mysql-python

Any ideas on why this is failing? I looked at other similar questions but the had ('s in their queries, this one is simple or I thought. Doesn't matter if I use a named parameter or sequential.

```
query = """
        SELECT idserver
        FROM server
        WHERE ipaddress=%(ipaddress)s
        """
self.c.execute(query, {'ipaddress': ip,})
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

Comment: I should also add that the problem lies in the WHERE clause, it does execute fine without the WHERE. The query also works fine natively, of course I put the value in the clause in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured this out but couldn't answer it. I was passing the whole tuple in for the value of ip rather than selecting the index. There is nothing wrong with this snippet of code.